# Understanding Minkowski's estimate for the product of successive minima from Cassel's book

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, convex-geometry, integer-lattices, diophantine-approximation

I wonder if there is a mistake in the proof of Theorem IV in section VIII.4.2 in Cassel's book on geometry of numbers. I refer to the claim in equation (12) on page 217 and its proof three equations later (see the highlighted section in the screenshot below).

[image]

Here $F$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, $J$ is an integer between $1$ and $n$ and for $w\in \mathbb{R}^{n-J}$,
$$
S_J(t,w)=\left\lbrace [x] \in \mathbb{R}^J/\mathbb{Z}^J : F(x,w) < t \right\rbrace.
$$
$m_J$ denotes the Haar measure on $\mathbb{R}^J/\mathbb{Z}^J$ induced by the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^J$.

**Question 1:** Does the highlighted portion above make sense? It seems to be implying that $$
F(y-y_0,sz) = F(y-y_0,z)
$$
which I cannot justify.

**Question 2:** If there is some mistake here, how do I prove the claim in equation (12) of the screenshot above?

Hope you can help me with this difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what is going on in Cassel's book but when I looked at the book of Gruber-Lekkerkerker, the following argument was suggested.
We let $\pi_J: \mathbb{R}^J \to \mathbb{R}^J/\mathbb{Z}^J$ be the projection. Recall that, for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $z \in \mathbb{R}^{n-J}$,
$$
S_J(t,z) := \pi_J \{x \in \mathbb{R}^J: F(x,z)<t\}.
$$
Assume $S_J(t,z) \neq \varnothing$ and choose $w \in \mathbb{R}^J$ so that we have
\begin{equation}\label{0}\tag{1}
0 \in w +\{x\in \mathbb{R}^J: F(x,z) < t\}.
\end{equation}
Using this, that $s\geq 1$, and the fact that $w+\{x \in \mathbb{R}^J: F(x,z)<t\}$ is convex, we see that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
m_J(S_J(st,sz)) &= m_J(\pi_J \{x \in \mathbb{R}^J: F(x,sz) < st\})\\
&= m_J(\pi_J (s\cdot\{y \in \mathbb{R}^J: F(y,z) < t\}))\\
&= m_J\left(\pi_J (s\cdot \{y \in \mathbb{R}^J: F(y,z) < t\} + \pi_J(s\cdot w)\right)\\
&= m_J\left(\pi_J (s\left( \{y \in \mathbb{R}^J: F(y,z) < t\} + w \right))\right) \\
&\geq m_J\left(\pi_J ( \{y \in \mathbb{R}^J: F(y,z) < t\} + w )\right)\ \text{ (Use the facts here)}\\
&=m_J(S_J(t,z) + \pi_J(w)) = m_J(S_J(t,z)).
\end{split}
\end{equation}